# What's the opposite of this full-text search?

Tags: mysql

I have:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(address) AGAINST('MockingBird')
```

Is there a way to do the opposite? ie return all rows that don't have 'MockingBird' in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT MATCH(address) AGAINST('MockingBird')
```